# Error while installing scipy and sklearn in PyCharm

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, pycharm, package

I am using PyCharm and I ran into some errors while installing scipy and sklearn but not numpy, matplotlib and pandas. I tried browsing "Christopher Gohkle's "Python Extension Packages For Windows" as this problem seems to happen before but the site is now refusing connection. Any other way to solve this problem? Thanks!
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOY5a.png)

Comment: It is generally a good idea to include the text of error messages in your question, rather than attaching them as externally hosted images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Christopher Gohkle's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) is up now. You can just check it out again.
But I suggest you to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) instead. It includes scipy and installation is so easy.